# Removing Items From Dropdown list (client side)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

So I have a number of dropdown select list controls populated as part of a repeater. They might contain overlapping data, meaning that the first d d list control will have selections:

```
a 
b
c
```

Second one:

```
c
d
e
```

Third one:

```
d
e
h
```

and so on.

So what I would like to do is to srart removing the duplicate items from the reset of drop down controls once the user starts selecting those. I intend to use jQuery for this.

Comment: @Chad Disabling instead of removing would be a better choice.

Comment: @Sime, how can you disable an item to not to be selected from a drop down list - this is not a list box item..

Comment: `item.disabled = true` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/option

Comment: @Te Chad I've made it work. :) See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the code is ugly, but at least it's short:

```
var selects = $('select');

selects.change(function() {
    var vals = {};    
    selects.each(function() { vals[this.value] = true; }).get();
    selects.not(this).children().not(':selected').not(':first-child')
        .each(function() { this.disabled = vals[this.value]; });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/bnehe/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery Form Wizard plugin. See: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/formwizard